# Detecting when network stack is loaded Win 7 embedded

Tags: windows, delphi, indy10

I am using win 7 embedded with explorer replaced so that the system boots direct to my application.

What I am finding is that by the time my application starts the network stack is not ready and I am failing to bind to any network addresses. Unfortunately its not a simple network requirements with a lot of different threaded parts starting at different times. There is a plug in system that may start network interfaces, a telnet interface, a UDP discovery broadcast thread etc.

Is there a simple way when my application starts to detect if the network stack is up and running?

The application is mostly Delphi using Indy components (but the plugins are c++ using asio).

The cheat solution at the moment is to put a 4sec sleep before the "Application.Initialize" and it always starts up correctly. If I put the sleep after the "Application.Initialize" so this suggests to me that there are components that are doing a WSAStartup in their initialize routine and this is what is breaking things.

Comment: What init procs are registered? Those are the things that run during `Application.Initialize`.

Comment: Sorry how do I list this. I was not aware that this was easily obtainable information.

Comment: Look for any units in your program that assign to `InitProc`. Or just step through `Application.Initialize` with Debug DCUs enabled. You really should make sure you understand what is happening in `Application.Initialize` in your program.

Answer (score 2):

Put the waiting call to `WSAStartup` in the `initialization` section of one of your unit, until the network success to initialize.

```
unit NetworkWaitUnit;

interface

implementation

uses
  Windows,
  yourWinSockUnit; 

var
  WsaDataOnce: TWSADATA;

const
  WinsockLevel = $0202;

initialization
  while not WSAStartup(WinsockLevel, WsaDataOnce) do
    sleep(100);
end.
```

Then ensure this unit is listed first in the `.dpr uses` unit list. As a result, it will be called before all other units, and your program should work as expected.

Something similar to that:

```
program MyServer;

uses
  NetworkWaitUnit, // should be listed first to be called first
  SysUtils,
  ...


end.
```

Comment: I did a quick test putting the code you suggested into the main unit just before "Application.Initialize" and it did not appear to catch the problem. I cant see how having it in an initialization section would be any different?

Comment: @Martin I think there's little point in you using trial and error here. You need to work out what happens in `Application.Initialize`. There's really no point in anyone guessing.

Comment: Looking at the MSDN this should work as you have described. It should return WSASYSNOTREADY until the subsystem is up and running.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I tried to step into the Application.Initialize but the IDE just stepped over it.

Comment: @Martin You should read my comment again. I said, with debug DCUs enabled.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan sorry - I did miss that. I am now able to step into this and it appears to call InitComObj and thats it. The call stack never went any deeper than that.

Comment: I am a little confused by this as I am sure I tested a SLEEP either side of the Application.Initialize and the problem only resolved itself when placed before.

Comment: @Martin I think it's pretty much futile asking the question at the moment because you have not diagnosed the problem. Perhaps Arnaud's answer is the solution to the problem, but nobody can be sure until the problem is successfully isolated. You need to do that first. You'll want to do some debugging.

Comment: @Martin @DavidHeffernan What I can assure you is that if you do what I wrote in there, you are **100% sure** that the code in the `initialization` section of the unit will be executed first, just after the `system.pas` and `sysinit.pas` units, and before `Application.Initialize`. Finding out how to wait properly for the network layer to be available in your particular case is not included, sorry... I relied on MSDN here, just as you do.

Comment: @Arnaud That's certainly true. Nobody doubts the order in which the code runs. I just don't believe martin has diagnosed the problem yet.

Comment: This is an established app (11 years) that we have just moved to an embedded platform. I doubt there is a "bug" in the networking as this continues to run fine under normal conditions. Even on the embedded system if I force the app closed and reopen it without restarting then it works fine. So what I do know is that its startup timing related. Doing more research this morning - appreciate the help so far.

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to not be the network stack but rather the specific interfaces. When various network components started they tried to bind to available ports. Because the app was starting so quickly the physical ports were not available and the nothing was bound.

The solution was to write a raw winsock routine to get a list of available ports and wait until the port count > 1 (need to account for the loopback) at the very start of the application.

For reference this is the API I used to get the interface list:

```
WSAIoctl(fSocket, SIO_GET_INTERFACE_LIST, Nil, 0, @InterfaceList, sizeof(InterfaceList), @BytesRet, Nil, Nil);
```